# Change of Variables over an $n$-dimensional ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I wish to understand what is going on in this change of variables, specifically what the transformation function and Jacobian are. The result is as follows, if we are integrating a function over a an $n$-dimensional ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin, then the following change of variables holds. Let $t \in [0,r]$ and $\omega \in \partial B_n(0,1)$, setting $y=t\omega$ gives,
$$
\int_{B_n(0,r)}f(y)dy=\int_0^r \int_{\partial B_n(0,1)} f(t\omega)t^{n-1}d\omega dt.
$$
I will explain my understanding and I would very much appreciate it if anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong. Let's specialise to $n=2$ for ease of calculations. To apply the change of variables we need to find an appropriate transformation function, I will call this $G$. Set $y=(y_1,y_2)=G(t,\omega)=(t\omega_1,t\omega_2)$. Now the problem is our $G$ is a function of 3 variables and not 2. However we can use the fact $\|\omega\|=\sqrt{\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2}=1$, thus we must have $\omega_2=\pm \sqrt{1-\omega_1^2}$. Our change of variables is then, $y=(y_1,y_2)=G(t,\omega)=(t\omega_1,t(\pm \sqrt{1-\omega_1^2}))$, which is now a function of two varibles as required, now we just calculate the Jacobian,
$$
\left| \dfrac{\partial G(t,\omega_1)}{\partial(t,\omega_1)}\right|=\begin{vmatrix}t & \omega_1 \\\ \dfrac{t\omega_1}{\pm\sqrt{1-\omega_1^2}}& \pm\sqrt{1-\omega_1^2}\end{vmatrix}= t\sqrt{1-\omega_1^2}-\dfrac{t\omega_1^2}{\sqrt{1-\omega_1^2}}=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-\omega_1^2}}.
$$
Thus we get this extra factor of $(\sqrt{1-\omega_1^2})^{-1}$. I don't know how to get rid of this, and I also don't like the fact I have a plus-minus hanging around. This argument easily generalizes to $n$-dimensions, and we get the Jacobian to be,
$$
\dfrac{t^{n-1}}{\sqrt{1-(\omega_1^2+\cdots+\omega_{n-1}^2)}}.
$$
This must be incorrect but I don't see why, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a fundamental obstruction here. What does $d\omega$ mean? Unless you specify that you cannot proceed. This is the reason why you are getting stuck.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for your comment, this is one of my issues, I don't know what this means rigorously and I can't find a good reference. In all posts I have seen or books I've looked at it is explained intuitively as integrating over the surface of the unit ball. I suppose what I'm really looking for is a rigorous proof of the above formula, or at least a reference as to where I might find one.

Comment: I’ve actually written several answers with sufficient rigor about related matters; if you know measure theory, you should be able to follow along: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4210663/568204) for what the surface measure is. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4059532/568204) for change of variables in general. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4218664/568204) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4179525/568204) for spherical measure. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4338718/568204) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4138970/568204) for curved Fubini

Comment: of course, for a sphere which is super nice, you don’t really need all this technology; you can just parametrize using spherical coordinates, and use the vanilla change-of-variables formula in the space of parameters. But in case you’re interested and want more gory details, I refer you to some of my answers above (and various sublinks, and references I may have suggested within). Also, I should say that while the coarea formula is nice, we don’t really need the full strength of it (I’ve never actually used it in full generality).

Comment: oh and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724490/568204) for a general measure-theoretic change-of-variables theorem and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4224651/568204) if you want to apply to the case of open sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, this is great, exactly what I was looking for, you’ve definitely made my life a lot easier with all of those references! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of variables formula does **not** apply directly to the spherical coordinates formula. That requires the [Coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) which is harder to prove.

Why doesn't it apply? Well, when precisely stated, (a version of) the change of variables formula applies to diffeomorphisms $U\cong V$ of **open** subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, for some $n$. With spherical coordinates, you're seeking to use $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}\cong(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$, which is true but not applicable. There is a problem with dimension (RHS lives most naturally in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$) and with openness ($S^{n-1}$ is not open in $\Bbb R^n$).

A third problem is that, while $\mathrm{d}\omega$ can be made to make sense, it's not the Lebesgue measure and the change of variables formula is a statement about integrating with Lebesgue measure, among other things. If you don't know what I mean by that, then I can rephrase it as this; integration against $\mathrm{d}\omega$ is *not* "ordinary" Riemann integration and the change of variables formula isn't applicable (directly).

So that's what's going wrong!

---

N.B. integration against $\mathrm{d}\omega$ around the sphere $S^{n-1}$ can be viewed (rigorously) as the measure-theoretic integral against the [Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) viewing $S^{n-1}$ as an $(n-1)$-dimensional metric space, up to a normalisation constant.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but for sets with a lot of symmetries such as the ball you don't really need all this advanced machinery.

Comment: @FShrike this is an excellent answer thank you very much, would you happen to be able to recommend a good reference to learn a bit more about the details?

Comment: @Emmet I personally don’t know how to prove the coarea formula, I’ve never investigated it. I would expect proofs can be found in textbooks on differential geometry or geometric measure theory. It’s possible there are simpler approaches for the special case of spherical coordinates

Comment: @FShrike, no problem, I'll do a bit of digging myself and if I happen to come across a very nice proof I'll link it in a comment in case you (or anyone else) are interested.

Comment: @Emmet Nice! ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

**NOT AN ANSWER - LONG COMMENT ON THE DEFINITION OF THE SURFACE INTEGRAL**

As I mentioned in comments, the problem is that $d\omega$ has not been defined. How are you supposed to compute
$$\tag{1}
\int_{\partial B(0,1)} f(\omega)\, d\omega,$$
with some explicit $f$ (such as, say $f(\omega)=\omega_1^2$)? If you do not know how to compute that, it makes little sense to try to use this symbol in more advanced computations.

This (1) is an example of a *surface integral*. Hypersurfaces such as $\partial B(0,1)$ do not have a preferred coordinate system. This is in contrast with the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, in which all definitions can be worked out in the standard Cartesian coordinate system and then pulled back to other coordinates if wanted. Therefore (1) does not really make sense until we choose a coordinate system, so that we can expand it in a ordinary multiple integral.

*Tangential remark*. Sometimes you cannot choose one single coordinate system for the whole surface. In that case you need to chop the integral in several parts. This is the fundamental idea of differential geometry.

For the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit sphere $\partial B(0, 1)$, which is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, a convenient coordinate system is the *polar coordinates*;
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x_n&= \cos \theta, \\ 
x_{n-1}&=\sin \theta \cos \phi_1, \\
x_{n-2}&=\sin \theta \sin \phi_1\cos \phi_2,\\  
\vdots & \\ 
x_2 &= \sin \theta \sin \phi_1\sin \phi_2\ldots \cos \phi_{n-2}, \\ 
x_1&= \sin \theta \sin \phi_1\sin \phi_2\ldots \sin \phi_{n-2}. \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

The $n=3$ case is detailed nicely on [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).

This coordinate system satisfies a very nice recursion relation that allows to define the surface element $d\omega_{n-1}$ on the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere $\partial B(0,1)$ recursively:
$$
d\omega_{n-1}=(\sin \theta)^{n-2}d\theta d\omega_{n-2}.$$
(I have commented a tiny bit on this formula in [this older answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3685528/8157), at the very end).

---

Only now that $d\omega$ has been defined we are in position to compute the formula
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(y)\, dy = \int_0^\infty \int_{\partial B(0,1)} f(t\omega)t^{n-1}dtd\omega.$$

I had thought of doing so, but I really cannot devote more time to this, so I am stopping here. Hope that what I wrote could be of some use nonetheless.

Comment: This is definitely an insightful remark and very much appreciated! Thanks.